# Calculate the number of boxes needed for a given set of items (weights)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a ms-sql table which looks like this (weight = kg).

[image: sample table]

I want to be able to calculate number of boxes and weight per box needed for an given identifier. A box can hold up to exactly 30 Kg. All items of that identifier can be mixed within a box. I am limited to sql only (2008) but everything can be used (CTE,Functions,StoredProcs and so on). I tried different approaches (CTE, functions) but i wasn't able to get the right results. any kind of help appreciated.

**Expected output**

when selecting identifier 100001:

[image]

when selecting identifier 100002:

[image]

when selecting identifier 100003:

[image]

when selecting identifier 100004:

[image]

**UPDATE**

**sample table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTest](
    [position] [int] NOT NULL,
    [item] [varchar](31) NOT NULL,
    [quantity] [money] NOT NULL,
    [weight] [money] NOT NULL,
    [identifier] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [position] ASC,
    [identifier] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**sample data**

```
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (1, N'0000001', 4.0000, 10.0000, N'100001')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (1, N'0000003', 3.0000, 15.0000, N'100002')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (1, N'0000006', 7.0000, 25.0000, N'100003')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (1, N'0000007', 1.0000, 1.5000, N'100004')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (1, N'0023021', 2.0000, 14.5000, N'100005')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (2, N'0000002', 1.0000, 15.0000, N'100001')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (2, N'0000004', 1.0000, 5.0000, N'100002')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (2, N'0000008', 1.0000, 2.5000, N'100004')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (2, N'0023022', 3.0000, 17.5000, N'100005')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (3, N'0000005', 3.0000, 2.5000, N'100002')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (3, N'0000009', 3.0000, 6.0000, N'100004')
INSERT [dbo].[tblTest] ([position], [item], [quantity], [weight], [identifier]) VALUES (4, N'0000010', 1.0000, 1.0000, N'100004')
```

Comment: This is (almost literally) a bin-packing problem.  I don't there is an efficient exact solution in SQL.

Comment: For more info on the bin packing problem...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: thank you two for the hint with the bin-packing. currently reading https://gertjans.home.xs4all.nl/sql/binpacking/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

See the demo here:  http://rextester.com/THP2733

**setup:**

```
create table tbl
(position integer, item integer, quantity integer, weight decimal(10,2), identifier integer);

insert into tbl
    select 1,  1, 4,  10, 100001 union all
    select 2,  2, 1,  15, 100001 union all
    select 1,  3, 3,  15, 100002 union all
    select 2,  4, 1,   5, 100002 union all
    select 3,  5, 3, 2.5, 100002 union all
    select 1,  6, 7,  25, 100003 union all
    select 1,  7, 1, 1.5, 100004 union all
    select 2,  8, 1, 2.5, 100004 union all
    select 3,  9, 3,   6, 100004 union all
    select 4, 10, 1,   1, 100004 ;
```

**query:**

```
with cte(position, item, quantity, weight, identifier, cntr)
as(select position, item, quantity, weight, identifier, quantity
   from tbl t1  
   union all   
   select t2.position, t2.item, t2.quantity, t2.weight, t2.identifier, cte.cntr - 1
   from tbl t2
   join cte 
     on t2.identifier = cte.identifier
    and t2.item = cte.item
    and cte.cntr > 1
)

select  
identifier,
sum(flg) over (partition by identifier order by item, cntr desc) package,
case when rolling_weight - lag(rolling_weight) over (partition by identifier order by cntr desc) is NULL then rolling_weight 
     else rolling_weight - lag(rolling_weight) over (partition by identifier order by cntr desc)
end weight
from 
(
    select temp1.*,
     case when rolling_weight % 30 = 0 then 1 
          when rolling_weight = total_weight then 1 
          when weight + lead(weight) over (partition by identifier order by cntr desc) > 30 then 1
          else 0 end as flg
    from
    (
        select 
          cte.*, 
          sum(weight) over (partition by identifier order by item, cntr desc) rolling_weight,
          sum(weight) over (partition by identifier) total_weight
        from cte
    ) temp1
) temp2
where flg = 1
order by identifier, package
```

Comment: thanks for your great effort mo2! Unfortunately as you can see in the tags of the question im on sql 2008. I dont want to be rude, but Is there any chance you can have a look at it again? LEAD and LAG are both MSSQL 2012 upwards according to the msdn.

Comment: if i add these 2 examples the result is incorrect. 
    
    select 1,11, 17.5, 3, 100005 union all
    select 2,12, 14.5, 2, 100005 
    
    result will be then 1 package with 30 and one with 49kg

Comment: Taking a look at the update with identifier 100005 now.  I should be able to tweak it to account for that.  As for lead/lag in sql 2008, there is an alternative but it gets pretty messy.  If I can get it working, I'll add an example of how to convert it.